# printf() function not working

Tags: c++, c

i have created a c program to print all possible strings of 8 characters. But the printf() function inside the program does not work at all. Here's the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
void ini(void);
void check(void);
void add(void);
static char str[9]; //permuting string
static char test[9]; //test string
static short int c = 1;
void print(char*);
void print(char a[]) {
    short int i,ln = (int)(strlen(str)-1);
    for(i = 0; i <= ln; i++)
    printf("%c",a[i]);
    printf("n");
}
void ini() {
    //initialzing the strings.
    short int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        str[i] = 'A';
        test[i]= 'z';
    }
    puts("ini.....");
    //initializing done
}
void check() {
    //check if the strings 'str' and 'test' are equal
    c = strcmp(str, test);
    puts("checking..........");
}
void add() {
    //this is the heart of the program
    short int i = 0;
    for( i = 7; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if((int)str[i] >= (int)'z') {
            str[i] = 'A';
            str[i-1]++;
        }
        else if(str[i] < 'z'){
            str[i]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    puts("adding.......");
}
int main() {
    //now we execute the functions above
    puts("in main.....");
    int i = 0;
    while( c != 0 ) //execute the loop while the permuting string 'str' is not equal to the final string 'test'
    {
        puts("inside while.......");
        for(i = 65; i <= 122; i++) { //loop to make the last character of 'str' permute from 'a' to'Z'
            str[7] = (char)i;
            puts("inside for");
            print(str); //print the whole string to the screen
        }
        add(); //change the next char
        check(); //check to see if 'str' has reached it's final point.
    }
    return 1;
    getch();
}
```

and here's the result.............

[image]

The program enters the for loop in main() but it does not execute the print() function. I have tried printf() but that shows the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `static char str[9]; //permuting string` is implicitly initialised to NULs (a side-effect of being `static`), then you overwrite character `[7]`, but the initial terminating NUL is still there at `[0]` such that `strlen()` in `print` considers it an empty string, `ln` is therefore `-1` and your `i <= ln` loop condition is never satisfied ==> nothing printed.

Comment: but in 'ini()' I set the str[0] to be 'A' instead of null.

Comment: then try calling `ini()` from `main()`: that's where the Operating System starts your program running.

Comment: how stupid of me!!!!!! Thanks a lot. Now the program runs just fine.

Comment: When using Visual Studio, start your program in Debug by pressing `F11` to "Step Into" the program. After that you can press `F11` to "step into" any function call or `F10` to continue to the next instruction.

Comment: @kfsone: the IDE in the image posted with the question isn't VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You decleared,

```
static char str[9];
```

So, all elements in `str` is `NULL` (`\0`) now. Then,

```
ln = (int)(strlen(str)-1);
```

Here, `strlen` counts characters until a `\0` found. So, as the first character in `str` is `\0`, `ln` will be `-1`. In the `for loop`,

```
for(i = 0; i <= ln; i++)
```

`i <= ln` condition will fail.

You may try, in the `main` function,

```
str[0] = (char) i;
```

or, call `ini()` before calling `print(str);`

But careful, your `while loop` will never break! As `c`'s never gonna be `0`.
Because your code does not changing the 9th character from `A` to `z` so strcmp(str, test) is not going to `return 0`.

Comment: The OP's code does not changing the 9th character from `A` to `z` so `strcmp(str, test)` is not going to return 0. I modified my answer. Ty.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I did not check the complete logic. Good point. Would you mind adding this info in the answer itself instead of leaving it as a comment? it's a rather important one.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `str` is a global static array, all elements are initialized to 0.

Next, in your code, you're only setting the index 7 and trying to pass the array to `print()` function. But the fact is, the very first element is a `null` (NOte: not a `NULL`, it's `null` which is `0` or `'\0'`). So, the call to `strlen()` inside `print()` will return a `0`. So, the immediate `printf()` will print nothing.

That said, I think, the next  `printf()` you meant to write as `printf("\n");`

**TL;DR Solution:** You're missing a call to `ini()` in your `main()` at the start, please add that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I did not call the ini() function from the main(). Calling it will initialize the strings so that the null byte is moved to the end. After that the program works just fine. So question closed.